# Agregar registro a tabla de forma predeterminada en ASP.NET MVC con Code-First

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Alguien que trabaje con el modelo **CodeFirst en ASP.NET MVC** y que me pueda dar una idea para saber: ¿Cómo agregar un usuario de forma predeterminada en la tabla **User**, al ejecutarse por primera vez la construcción de las tablas de mi Context?
Pongo este fragmento simple de 3 tablas que se crean en el proyecto. Realmente la que me interesa es la tabla **User**, ya que es en ella donde quiero que de forma predeterminada se **cree UN usuario** (ADMIN), inmediatemente después de creada la tabla. Note que la columna **user_id_created** deberá ser **REQUIRED**, para que **SOLO** los posteriores registros almacenen qué usuario fue el que los creo.
Espero ser lo más claro y simple para darme a entender qué es lo que quiero hacer.
Les agradezco de antemano el interés y/o ayuda.

```
class Project_Context : DbContext
{
    public Project_Context() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
    public DbSet<State> States { set; get; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { set; get; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { set; get; }
}
public class User
{
    [Column("user_id")]
    [Key]
    public int Id { set; get; }
    [Column("user_email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    [Index("user_user_email", IsClustered = false, IsUnique = false, Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} puede contener máximo {1} y mínimo {2} caracteres", MinimumLength = 7)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es requerido")]
    public string Email { set; get; }
    [Column("user_password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es requerido")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} puede contener máximo {1} y mínimo {2} caracteres", MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Password { set; get; }
    [Column("city_id")]
    [Display(Name = "Ciudad")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es requerido")]
    public int IdCity { set; get; }
    public virtual City City { set; get; }
    [Column("user_id_created")]
    [Display(Name = "Creado por usuario")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es requerido")]
    public int IdUserCreated { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: cuando crear la estructura en base a EF, aplicar migrations ? porque podrias definir el usuario admin en la operacion de Seed()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas `migrations` para crear la estructura de la base de datos

[Use Code First Migrations to Seed the Database](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3)

podrias durante esta operacion crear el usuario en el metodo `Seed()`

[Seeding ASP.NET Identity Database](http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/seeding-aspnet-identity-database_25.html)

En la clase que crea migrations podrias usar las clases

```
 protected override void Seed(ProfileManagement.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
    var hasher = new PasswordHasher();
    var user = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = "abhimanyu",
        PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword("abhimanyu"),
        UserProfileInfo = new UserProfileInfo
        {
            FirstName = "Abhimanyu K",
            LastName = "Vatsa",
            EmailID = "abhikumarvatsa@yahoo.co.in"
        }
    };

    manager.Create(user, "abhimanyu");
}
```